# How to setup JBoss server with Netbeans?

Tags: netbeans, jboss

I'm trying to setup jBoss 7 server with NetBeans Wizard but it says "Provide a valid jBoss Application Server 6, 5 or 4 Location". I downloaded version 6 too to give it a try and it worked fine. What is the proper way of adding jBoss 7 on netbeans IDE 7.1.2??

Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573818/error-configuring-jboss-7-with-netbeans7

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The official support for JBoss AS 7 is not available yet for Netbeans 7.1.x.

- Netbeans Bug report : [Bug 200132 - Add support for JBoss AS 7](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=200132)
- List of [Netbeans supported technologies](http://netbeans.org/community/releases/71/relnotes.html#supported_technologies) (JBoss 6.1 is the last supported version)

But according to [this](http://javadude.wordpress.com/2012/08/24/netbeans-and-jboss-7/) link, there is an unofficial plugin, that can manage server, but can't deploy application on JBoss AS 7.

Comment: NetBeans 7.3.1 now has support for JBoss 7, so if it's possible to upgrade to this version you don't need to use any unofficial pugins.

Answer (score 4):

To deploy on build, and undeploy on clean for:

- Enterprise Application project (EAR)
- Web Application projects (WAR)

Copy this ant script to the 'build.xml' file inside your project, ***and change*** the property jboss.dir to your path:

```
<project>

    ...

    <property name="jboss.dir" 
         value="D:/Share/Sync/Dev/tools/j/jboss-as-7.1.1.Final/standalone/deployments"/>

    <target depends="-post-clean" name="post-clean"/>
    <target depends="-jboss-env" name="-post-clean">
        <echo>Undeploying: ${jboss.projectFile}</echo>
        <delete file="${jboss.dir}/${jboss.projectFile}"/>
        <delete file="${jboss.dir}/${jboss.projectFile}.${jboss.projectState}"/>
    </target>

    <target depends="-post-dist" name="post-dist"/>
    <target depends="-jboss-env" name="-post-dist">
        <echo>Deploying: ${jboss.projectFile}</echo>
        <copy file="${dist.dir}/${jboss.projectFile}" todir="${jboss.dir}"/>
        <delete file="${jboss.dir}/${jboss.projectFile}.failed" /> 
    </target>

    <target name="-jboss-env" >
        <condition property="jboss.projectFile" value="${war.name}">
            <isset property="war.name"/>
        </condition>
        <condition property="jboss.projectFile" value="${jar.name}">
            <isset property="jar.name"/>
        </condition>
        <available property="jboss.projectState" 
                   file="${jboss.dir}/${jboss.projectFile}.undeployed" 
                   value="undeployed"/>
        <available property="jboss.projectState" 
                   file="${jboss.dir}/${jboss.projectFile}.failed" 
                   value="failed"/>
        <available property="jboss.projectState" 
                   file="${jboss.dir}/${jboss.projectFile}.deployed" 
                   value="deployed"/>
    </target>

</project>
```

Answer (score 2):

Pretty late reply, but some update, JBoss 7.1.1 worked with Netbeans 7.4 for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar simptoms with Netbeans 8 - JBoss 7.2

For me somebody deleted - or didn't exist - the 'lib' folder from standalone. As I put it back from somewhere else, it worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

I use netbeans 8.0 and installed jboss 6.4 on ubuntu 16.
To do it:

1. Download JBoss https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/jboss_enterprise_application_platform/6.3/html/getting_started_guide/sect-download_and_install_jboss_eap_using_the_zip
2. Unzip it into a folder of your choice
3. Go to your netbeans under tools > Servers
4. Click "Add server"
5. Select JBoss in the choose server window
6. In the server location, specify the extracted jBoss folder
7. Click next then click finish

You might have to create a RedHat account. I hope that this helps.

Answer (score 0):

According to this: http://developinjava.com/articles/using-jboss-as-7-with-netbeans/

The development Version of netbeans has support for jboss 7.

Have not tested it though. Because my problem is that my jboos install is on a diffrent machine and it looks like it need to be local to be supported. :(