# Error configuring JBoss 7 with Netbeans7

Tags: jboss7.x, netbeans-7

I want to configure Jboss 7.1.1 final in Netbeans 7.0.1. But I am getting an error "Provide a JBoss application server 6,5,4 Location". How can I add the latest JBoss AS?

Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: refer this it may help you http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=203155

Comment: I have found the patch. But I am unable to add this patch into netbeans.

Comment: can u post the link where u  found the patch

Comment: above link you have provide to me.

Comment: http://bugzilla-attachments-200132.netbeans.org/bugzilla/attachment.cgi?id=118250

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11557940/how-to-setup-jboss-server-with-netbeans

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, NetBeans doesn't support JBoss AS 7 at least as of NetBeans 7.2. A [patch](http://netbeans.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=200132) adding support has existed for some time, but was unfortunately not merged for the 7.2 release. There seems to be relatively little interest in AS7 in the NetBeans community.

I eventually gave up on NetBeans supporting AS 7 and moved to [JBoss Developer Studio](http://www.jboss.com/products/devstudio/) - basically a roll-up of Eclipse and JBoss Tools with preinstalled AS7 support, some bug fixes and polish.

There are a few NetBeans features I miss and it took a little learning, but overall I'm happy and there's enough really good stuff that I'm not going to bother going back.

Answer (score 0):

I was stuck with JBoss 6.1 until I coded my own solution to deploy my projects.

Check the ant script here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/13372389/980442